# Ajax post not working in IE11on Windows 8 no error returned

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

The same code worked in chrome on mac:

```
$.ajax({
        url     : 'change.php',
        method  : 'POST',
        data    : {"id" : id, 'name': name},
        success : function( response ) {
            alert(response)
        }
    });
```

No alert is shown. I am assuming it is not successful. Any ideas?

### UPDATE

There's no error showing in the developer's console

Comment: Look for possible errors in the developer console.

Comment: There is no error block  in the ajax, so how are you seeing error?

Comment: Are you using https? I noticed in IE11 it is much more sensitive on httpsand  if it uses correct ceritificate.

Comment: @user2181397 by error I meant the errors in developer's console

Comment: Use ajax error handler. Also can inspect any request in network tab of dev tools for clues

Comment: @ShiraNai7 no there's no error showing

Comment: put an error block in the ajax and check the error message

Comment: add this line in <head> tag <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,chrome=1">

Answer (score -1):

try this:

test.php

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

index.html

```
<script   src="jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script>
var p1=1;
var p2 = 23;
$.ajax({
        url     : "test.php",
        method  : "POST",
        data    : {param1:p1,param2:p2},
        success : function( response ) {
            console.log(response);
            alert(response);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How does this help solve OP's problem? The term `try this` is not a proper explanation by itself